# Attack with two keywords versus resistance with one of them

Tags: dnd-4e

I had the following situation last night. A creature attacked with a Fire and Poison attack. My character has resist 5 Poison. does the resistance apply or do I need to resist 5 fire as well?

Answer (score 18):

**You need resistance to both keywords to properly resist the attack.**

From [DDI](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/glossary.aspx?id=130):

> **Against Combined Damage Types:** Your resistance is ineffective against combined damage types unless you have resistance to each of the damage types, and then only the weakest of the resistances applies. For example, if you have resist 10 lightning and resist 5 thunder and an attack deals 15 lightning and thunder damage to you, you take 10 damage, because the resistance to the combined damage types is limited by the lesser of the two resistances.

Comment: Yep, so in your case you would take the full damage unless you also had resistance to fire.

Comment: is this different from 3.5?  I seem to recall there being a spell (divine i think) that dealt holy and fire, but resisting the fire only reduced the spell's damage by 50%.

Comment: @acolyte aside form the general framework of classes, magic items, d20 rolls, and modifier math you should treat 4e as wholly separate from 3.5 from a rules mechanics perspective. Source material its a direct reinterpretation/sequel, but the mechanics and more importantly the game development philosophy that went into them are extremely different from 3.5.

Comment: @JoshuaAslanSmith I know that much, i was just surprised that the rules for dual-damage were so different from what I (thought) i remembered.  unless i'm thinking of a specific spell and not the general rule.

Comment: @Acolyte the spell that does holy and fire in 3.5e specifically dealt half holy, half fire damage. No single point of damage had both types at once.

Answer (score 9):

The attack is Fire *and* Poison, as such it isn't resisted unless all the keywords are resisted.

From the latest PhB errata:

> Resistance or immunity to one keyword of a power
>   does not protect a target from the power’s other
>   effects. Also, resistance doesn’t reduce damage unless
>   the target has resistance to each type of damage
>   from the attack, and then only the weakest of the
>   resistances applies. For example, a character who has
>   resist 10 lightning and resist 5 thunder who takes
>   15 lightning and thunder damage takes 10 damage
>   because the resistance value to the combined damage
>   types is limited by the lesser of the two resistances.

Answer (score 2):

Yet, if you have Resist Fire 10 and Resist Poison 5, you will reduce only 5 damage from this attack, not 10, the lowest resistance between both applies.