# How do Invulnerabilities Interact with Multiple Damage Types?

Tags: dnd-4e

If an attack does, say, 10 Radiant and Fire Damage and the target has 5 Fire invulnerability? Do they take no damage, or half damage?

I see that [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/11804/23064) covers resistances, however, I wasn't sure if the same applied to invulnerability, which wasn't covered in the linked question.

Comment: You can just reword this question to be about invulnerability and then it will not be a duplicate.

Comment: @GreedyRadish The same rules apply to both resistance and immunity, as the second answer to that question shows.

Comment: @DuckTapeAl I know that, but that is exactly what this question wants to be asking. It is a two part question where one part is a duplicate and one part is not.

Comment: @GreedyRadish The immunity question has been asked before as well: http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/76827/does-immunity-to-a-keyword-in-a-multi-effect-power-confer-immunity-to-the-whole

Comment: @DuckTapeAl That question refers to keywords, not damage types.